# Best way for z-ordering sprites on isometric map with cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, isometric

after few headaches i figured out that using `CCSpriteBatchNode` with cocos2d olny allows to z-order sprites added to it as child (which is obvious, now i see..)

```
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"token_default.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *tokenSpriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"token_default.png"];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"objects_default.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *objectsSpriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"objects_default.png"];

    CCSprite *token = [[[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"token_SE.png"] autorelease];
    [token setPosition:tokenSpawnPoint];
    CCSprite *enemy = [[[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"token_blak_SE.png"] autorelease];
    [enemy setPosition:enemySpawnPoint];
    CCSprite *houseA = [[[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"house_small.png"] autorelease];
    [houseA setPosition:[self randomHousePosition]];
    CCSprite *houseB = [[[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"house_big.png"] autorelease];
    [houseB setPosition:[self randomHousePosition]];

    [tokenSpriteSheet addChild:token];
    [tokenSpriteSheet addChild:enemy];
    [objectsSpriteSheet addChild:houseA];
    [objectsSpriteSheet addChild:houseB];
```

and since i have to add them to the display list as follows..

```
    [_isoMap addChild:objectsSpriteSheet];
    [_isoMap addChild:tokenSpriteSheet];
```

there is no way i can change the z-order of single tokens between other houses...
they will be always rendered over the house until i change the order of these batch nodes

btw, i can "merge" all sprites' arts in one big single batch node... doing so it became possible to order sprites using sprite's coordinates

```
    [fullSpriteSheet reorderChild:token z:token.position.y];
```

i'm a little stuck with it...... is there a way to achieve that, having different sprite bacth nodes? or is possible to programmatically merge two batchnodes? (or something like that)

i found [KnightFight](https://github.com/lozarcher/KnightFight), a really interesting open project on github by LozArcher.. he used `CCSpriteFrame` and `CCSprite`'s `setDisplayFrame` method, instead of batch nodes... but i can't run it since it seems to be an older version of cocos2d (apparently not working with xcode 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that changing the `vertexZ` property of a `CCNode` (like a `CCSprite`) it actually changes its Z position (so it will be slightly bigger/smaller, and also translated)

so, in order to arrange on z-index CCSprites with different spriteSheet i had to use `reorderChild` method (to just change the rendering order) and mostly i need NOT TO USE `CCSpriteBatchNode`..

after a little refactoring of the above example, i should have:

```
CCSprite *token = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"token_SE.png"];
[token setPosition:tokenSpawnPoint];
CCSprite *enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"token_blak_SE.png"];
[enemy setPosition:enemySpawnPoint];

CCSprite *houseA = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"house_small.png"];
[houseA setPosition:[self randomHousePosition]];
CCSprite *houseB = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"house_big.png"];
[houseB setPosition:[self randomHousePosition]];

[_isoMap addChild:token];
[_isoMap addChild:enemy];
[_isoMap addChild:houseA];
[_isoMap addChild:houseB];
```

i also added each sprite to a `NSMutableArray`
and then in a for loop (inside the `update` scheduled method):

```
CCSprite *sprite = [mySpritesArray objectAtIndex:i];
[_isoMap reorderChild:sprite z:(_isoMap.mapSize.height - sprite.y)];
```

hope this could help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I still think that is not better solution,
if your objects on map are moving dynamically, you can still stuck in z order issues.

I know its very old post, and people keep coming here by google search,
so I am posting solution here.

```
float lowestZ = tilemap.map.width +tilemap.map.height ;
float currentZ = self.gridLocation.x + self.gridLocation.y ;
int zOrderDecided = lowestZ + currentZ - 1 ;
[self.parent reorderChild:self z:zOrderDecided];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Sprites Z order to it's Y position on the map. Reorder your dynamic sprites in an update loop. Calculate the Z order using the Sprites current Y position and the visible height of the map.

```
void LocalGameController::SetZOrderForObject(cocos2d::Sprite *object){
  int objectZOrder = visibleSize.height - object->getPositionY();
  context->reorderChild(object, objectZOrder);
}
```